# Why am I getting an access denied error on the second file (a text file) for mysqldump using the tab option?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to backup a mysql db on Ubuntu using the `--tab` option using the following:

```
mysqldump -umy_user my_database -p --tab=/path/to/backup/dir
```

I enter the password and then get the following error:

> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user
>   'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when executing
>   'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'

The password is okay, and `File` is in the list from `show privileges` for the user. Additionally it looks like I can produce .sql files, but it dies on the first .txt file. Also a mysqldump to just a plain .sql file works.

After running the command and seeing the error, if I ls the backup dir I see one sql file that looks correct of structure, but it seems to have died trying to write the first txt file of table contents.

I created an empty dir for the dump ahead of time. I tried chmoding it to 777 and before that I tried chowning it to `mysql:mysql`.

Comment: Are you allowed to write to the destination directory/file?

Comment: @neuhaus yes, the destination is owned by my user... I also tried chowning it to `mysql:mysql`, but neither worked. I also tried chmoding it to 777.

Comment: Once try:  **mysqldump --databases database_name > my_database_dump.txt**

Comment: @raj_on_rails that works fine (I added in -umy_user)... if it's one file for output it works... if it's the tab option it write the first file into the dir and then dies before the second.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: Great.

Comment: @raj_on_rails ... not really, I want the --tab option to output each table as a separate file... I can only output everything into one giant file :(

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT @secure_file_priv`?

Comment: Just an idea, it is probably a dead end but it's worth trying: does Ubuntu come with [`SELinux`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) or something similar installed? I know Fedora uses it and I know I had to disable it (on Fedora) to make MySQL server run the way I want.

Comment: @axiac thanks, but no selinux installed. which selinux returns nothhing and there is no  `/selinux/enforce` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [apparmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) is causing this.

Since the mysql user has the correct permission, and you tried setting the file permissions and owners, the thing that is left is something other than mysql or file permissions. On Ubuntu this would be apparmor.

To verify that mysqld is effected, try:

```
> sudo aa-status

...
2 processes are in enforce mode.
/usr/sbin/mysqld (1182)
...
```

Once verified, you have to tell apparmor to allow mysqld to write to your backup dir. The permissions are stored in: `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

```
...
/usr/sbin/mysqld {
    ....
    /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
    /path/to/backup/dir/** w,
}
```

You can add write permission to the directory you want to backup as in the example above.

And just for reference, here is the directory ownership that was required in addition to the apparmor changes:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /path/to/backup/dir
```

As a final note that sheds a little more light on why the first file was written and then errored out, the ownership of the dumped files was not uniform. For whatever reason the sql files were owned by the shell user running the command and the txt files were owned by mysql:

```
> ls -al /path/to/backup/dir
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 my_user my_user  1596 Feb  2 01:24 wp_terms.sql
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql   mysql    5117 Feb  2 01:24 wp_terms.txt
...
```

Answer (score 4):

*While this works on my end for a problem with the exact same symptoms, this apparently does not solve the OP's problem. I'm leaving this here for reference and for other people who get this error.*

## Problem:

You will get this error if your MySQL user does not have `FILE` `PRIVILEGE_TYPE`, which is separate from file system permissions and not listed by `show privileges` (see documentation below). You can check all of your user's permissions by running the following query after connecting using the `mysql` command.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

Or, enter this handy one-liner into your shell.

```
echo 'SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();' | mysql -u my_user -p
```

If you have these permissions, you will get a response containing `GRANT FILE` or `GRANT ALL ON *.*`, on a line resembling the following.

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*hash'
```

If you do not receive a line like this, you will need to grant the user this permission.

Alternately, you can check that your user has these permissions in the `USER_PRIVILEGES` table of the `information_scheme` database.

## Solution:

To permission your user, log in as a sufficiently-privileged user, and run the following command.

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* to 'my_user'@'localhost';
```

## Documentation:

From [the `mysqldump` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for `--tab=path, -T path`:

> **Note**
>
> This option should be used only when `mysqldump` is run on the same machine as the `mysqld` server. You must have the `FILE` privilege, and the server must have permission to write files in the directory that you specify.

Comment: In the op I statle that, `File` is in the list from `show privileges` for the user. 
The grants shown do not include file separately, because it's just one grant all privileges.

Comment: I'm running on the same machine, and I've chmoded the directory and chowned it in various ways. The really weird thing is that mysqldump will in fact write one correctly looking sql file into the directory before  the error happens... the error happens on the second file.

Comment: @PeterAjtai `show privileges` is different from `show grants`, sorry I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: @PeterAjtai Can you add the output you get from `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();`? You can strip sensitive info. I get the exact same error as you when a user does not have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Sure it is 2 lines: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ....`, and `GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO ...`

Comment: @PeterAjtai Are you using a proxy user?

Comment: No, I've tried this with both root, and a user specific to the database. Neither one are proxy users.

Comment: The root MySQL user wasn't able to do it either? Can you check if the `FILE` permission is listed in `information_scheme.USER_PRIVILEGES`, just to be sure?

Comment: Yeah, I see File for the root user in `information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGS`.

Comment: @PeterAjtai Is it for `'root'@'localhost'`, `'root'@'127.0.0.1'`, `'root'@'::1'`, or all of these?

Comment: it is for all 3 of those and `'root'@'%' `

Comment: @PeterAjtai Well, I'm completely out of ideas. I've added a note so other people will know this doesn't solve your problem. Good luck on this, it's a tough one.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions Alexander. I finally figured it out! http://stackoverflow.com/a/28269447/186636

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` runs [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) to dump the data as CSV or tab-separated values 
(when `--tab` is used).

A note near the end of the manual page of [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) says:

> If the [`secure_file_priv`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be written must be located in that directory.

*"By default, the variable `secure_file_priv` is empty"* -- says the official documentation, but sometimes the bundlers use customized configurations.

Check the value of this variable on your system using:

```
SELECT @secure_file_priv;
```

If it is not `NULL` then you have to either reset it or use the path it contains to dump your files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `@secure_file_prive`, but the value is `NULL`.